# Beego request cycle hooks

Tags: go, beego

I want to know if Beego has some hooks that I can use for every request in app to inject some functionality. For instance, BeforeControllerLoads or AfterInitRequestLoads. I did not found any of similar hooks. ORM hooks do not fit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **controller** you have both `Prepare` and `Finish`:

```
// Prepare runs after Init before request function execution.
func (c *Controller) Prepare() {}

// Finish runs after request function execution.
func (c *Controller) Finish() {}
```

Also via **filters** you can insert any hook:

```
beego.InsertFilter("/user/:id([0-9]+)", beego.BeforeRouter, FilterUser)
```

You have different execution points:

```
// default filter execution points
const (
    BeforeStatic = iota
    BeforeRouter
    BeforeExec
    AfterExec
    FinishRouter
)
```

https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/develop/controller.go
https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/develop/router.go